# someone who just cares and follows where his own interests to?

Tags: adjectives, epithet-requests

What do you call someone who just cares about his own interests, doesn't look people up out of love or care or to check up on them. But just feigning to do while he panders mostly indirectly to end up asking for a favour for his own interest. He acts on the outside like he's supportive and loyal but in truth he only cares about his own interests.

The word in my language stems from the word interest. I can't happen to find that in English. Hoping you can approximate me to a reasonable answer.

Any suggestions are welcome, phrases anything.

Comment: *ego-centric*, *egoistic*

Answer (score 1):

He's selfish.

"Someone who is selfish only thinks of their own advantage:"
The judge told him: "Your attitude shows a selfish disregard for others."
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/selfish

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the term "hypocrite" as you mentioned the one who shows love and care, but within just someone who entirely opposite to that.

Answer (score 1):

The person the OP describes is ***self-centered***, as defined at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self%E2%80%93centered)

> concerned solely with one's own desires, needs, or interests

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-centered) says:

> engrossed in self; selfish; egotistical

Answer (score 0):

Sycophant

> praising people in authority in a way that is not sincere, usually in order to get some advantage from them

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sycophantic